# How to append multiple elements to a repeatedField in Protocol buffers?

Tags: c++, vector, protocol-buffers

Given a message

```proto
message My_msg{
  repeated double my_arr = 1;
}
```

How can one append elements into the field?

[There is an answer for copying/moving already allocated full arrays by overwriting the current contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57458319/c-protobuf-add-an-already-allocated-repeated-numeric-field/), but what if there is already some data in the filed, which needs to be kept as it is?

Is using the below code to do it safe?

```cpp
void set_data(std::vector<double> table, My_msg* message){ /* suppose message is valid */
  message->mutable_my_arr()->Resize(message->my_arr_size() + table.size(),0);
  message->mutable_my_arr()[message->my_arr_size() - table.size()] = {table.begin(),table.end()};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your sample code would build. `My_msg::mutable_my_arr()` returns a pointer to a `RepeatedField` (not the first element of an array). Trying to index it would segfault at best.

In terms or performance, if you have your data in an `std::vector` you will always need to copy - so you could just try to make that faster.

You can call [`RepeatedField::Reserve`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.repeated_field#RepeatedField.Reserve.details) before. Then you can either write a loop, or use `RepeatedFieldBackInserter`:

```cpp
void set_data(const std::vector<double>& table, My_msg* message){
  message->mutable_my_arr()->Reserve(message->my_arr_size() + table.size());
  std::copy(
      table.begin(),
      table.end(), 
      RepeatedFieldBackInserter(message->mutable_my_arr()));
}
```

Comment: But it does compile. [It's list initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49822561/1467600) combined with the copy equality operator. The assumption of segfault might be true however. Thank you for the tip, std::copy seems to be the way here.

Comment: I think you're right that it builds, but it would try to access the `RepeatedField` as the first element of an array, which would probably segfault. That said, the only real point of this answer is to use `Reserve`, everything else is details.

Comment: Can confirm, compilation success but segfault upon usage. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just call `My_msg::add_my_arr`:

```
void set_data(std::vector<double> table, My_msg* message) {
    for (auto ele : table) {
        message->add_my_arr(ele);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that waste cycles? shouldn't the other method be more optimized?